# Resolution app kinect

Tags: kinect, resolution

I've installed the Windows Interaction Gallery application for Kinect and when I run the program, this resolution warning comes up. The program was designed to work on a higher resolution than my monitor has. I've attached a picture in order to explain better what message I get. Do you know how I can fix this problem? What file should I change?

PS:oh, sorry. i forgot to put in the link with the image
http://i39.tinypic.com/2cqedti.jpg

Comment: where's the picture ?

Comment: Can you not just hit continue and carry on?

Comment: if i don't click Yes, the app closes. i want to change the resolution so that it can also run on monitors with a lower resolution than 1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the program was designed for a **higher resolution** than your monitor currently supports. Fixing this problem isn't a simple matter of changing a file on your computer... But rather getting a monitor that supports the resolution of 1920x1080.

Of course I doubt this error will stop you from doing anything. Apart from possible layout issues, everything should still 'work' if you click 'Yes' on the message to continue running the program.

**Sidenote:**

If this is a problem with the simulation screen, then you could do this:

To change the simulated screen size and resolution, choose the Change Resolution button on the palette and choose a new size and resolution from the list.

[image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC566777.png]

**Edit:**

The button you need is the last one on the right of the simulator:

[image]

Comment: So i can't make the error go away? Or change the way the program works on a lower resolution.Where can I find the button you took a screenshot of? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: If you're using the simulator in Visual Studio then you can just simply change the resolution of the simulator itself. This should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh441475.ASPx

Comment: How can I get this simulator that you're talking about? Here's a screenshot of my Visual Studio window. I can't seem to find any simulator here.  http://i44.tinypic.com/eldu2c.jpg

Comment: The screenshots I took were for Visual Studio 2012, looks like you are using 2010. If everything is set up properly however, hitting F5 to run the project should just start up the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

```
private const int MinimumScreenWidth = 1920;
private const int MinimumScreenHeight = 1080;

 if ((width < MinimumScreenWidth) || (height < MinimumScreenHeight))
        {
            MessageBoxResult continueResult = MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.SuboptimalScreenResolutionMessage, Properties.Resources.SuboptimalScreenResolutionTitle, MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (continueResult == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

I've found these 2 code sequences which at first sight seem to be connected with my problem. I've tried to change the size of the 2 constans but without much success. I've attached the code, so you can see it better.

Comment: That code is just doing a check to see if your screen resolution is 1920x1080.. If it isn't a message box will show. Of course if you hit no `this.Close();` will close the app. Hitting yes however will cause the app to run as per normal... If you don't want your app to run this check every time it starts up you could just remove that block of code.